# How to re-format laravel relationship collections

Tags: php, laravel, dictionary, collections, cart

I have the following models and their relationships:

Product - (name, price, qty)

Product Attribute (qty, price - when there is a combination, the qty and price here is the one getting)

Attribute - (size, color)

Attribute Values - (small, medium, large, red, blue, green etc)

```
// One to Many Relationship
$product->productAttributes (returns a collection)

// Many to Many Relationship
$productAttribute->attributeValues (returns a collection)

// One to Many Relationship
$attribute->attributeValues
```

I need to format it in such a way like:

```
array:2 [
  "color" => array:2 [
    0 => "red"
    1 => "blue"
  ]
  "size" => array:3 [
    0 => "small"
    1 => "medium"
    2 => "large"
  ]
]
```

This is what I get when I iterate on the collections:

```
    $attributes = $productAttributes->map(function (ProductAttribute $pa){
        return $pa->attributesValues->map(function (AttributeValue $av) {
            return [$av->attribute->name => $av->value];
        });
    })->all();
```

it obviously returns:

```
array:6 [▼
  0 => Collection {#508 ▼
    #items: array:2 [▼
      0 => array:1 [▼
        "Color" => "red"
      ]
      1 => array:1 [▼
        "Size" => "small"
      ]
    ]
  }
  1 => Collection {#525 ▼
    #items: array:2 [▼
      0 => array:1 [▼
        "Color" => "red"
      ]
      1 => array:1 [▼
        "Size" => "medium"
      ]
    ]
  }
  2 => Collection {#535 ▼
    #items: array:2 [▼
      0 => array:1 [▼
        "Color" => "red"
      ]
      1 => array:1 [▼
        "Size" => "large"
      ]
    ]
  }
  3 => Collection {#545 ▼
    #items: array:2 [▼
      0 => array:1 [▼
        "Color" => "red"
      ]
      1 => array:1 [▼
        "Size" => "small"
      ]
    ]
  }
]
```

Again, my intent is to format it like this:

```
array:2 [
  "color" => array:2 [
    0 => "red"
    1 => "blue"
  ]
  "size" => array:3 [
    0 => "small"
    1 => "medium"
    2 => "large"
  ]
]
```

TIA!

Edit:

```
$product->productAttributes

    Collection {#513 ▼
      #items: array:6 [▼
        0 => ProductAttribute {#514 ▼
          #fillable: array:2 [▶]
          #connection: "mysql"
          #table: null
          #primaryKey: "id"
          #keyType: "int"
          +incrementing: true
          #with: []
          #withCount: []
          #perPage: 15
          +exists: true
          +wasRecentlyCreated: false
          #attributes: array:6 [▶]
          #original: array:6 [▼
            "id" => 7
            "quantity" => 3
            "price" => "100.00"
            "product_id" => 25
            "created_at" => "2018-03-11 16:56:36"
            "updated_at" => "2018-03-11 16:56:36"
          ]
          #changes: []
          #casts: []
          #dates: []
          #dateFormat: null
          #appends: []
          #dispatchesEvents: []
          #observables: []
          #relations: []
          #touches: []
          +timestamps: true
          #hidden: []
          #visible: []
          #guarded: array:1 [▶]
        }
        1 => ProductAttribute {#515 ▶}
        2 => ProductAttribute {#516 ▶}
        3 => ProductAttribute {#517 ▶}
        4 => ProductAttribute {#518 ▶}
        5 => ProductAttribute {#519 ▶}
      ]
    }

    $productAttribute->attributeValues

array:6 [▼
  0 => Collection {#507 ▼
    #items: array:2 [▼
      0 => AttributeValue {#521 ▼
        #fillable: array:1 [▶]
        #connection: "mysql"
        #table: null
        #primaryKey: "id"
        #keyType: "int"
        +incrementing: true
        #with: []
        #withCount: []
        #perPage: 15
        +exists: true
        +wasRecentlyCreated: false
        #attributes: array:5 [▶]
        #original: array:7 [▼
          "id" => 1
          "value" => "red"
          "attribute_id" => 1
          "created_at" => "2018-03-11 16:49:15"
          "updated_at" => "2018-03-11 16:49:15"
          "pivot_product_attribute_id" => 7
          "pivot_attribute_value_id" => 1
        ]
        #changes: []
        #casts: []
        #dates: []
        #dateFormat: null
        #appends: []
        #dispatchesEvents: []
        #observables: []
        #relations: array:1 [▶]
        #touches: []
        +timestamps: true
        #hidden: []
        #visible: []
        #guarded: array:1 [▶]
      }
      1 => AttributeValue {#506 ▼
        #fillable: array:1 [▶]
        #connection: "mysql"
        #table: null
        #primaryKey: "id"
        #keyType: "int"
        +incrementing: true
        #with: []
        #withCount: []
        #perPage: 15
        +exists: true
        +wasRecentlyCreated: false
        #attributes: array:5 [▶]
        #original: array:7 [▶]
        #changes: []
        #casts: []
        #dates: []
        #dateFormat: null
        #appends: []
        #dispatchesEvents: []
        #observables: []
        #relations: array:1 [▶]
        #touches: []
        +timestamps: true
        #hidden: []
        #visible: []
        #guarded: array:1 [▶]
      }
    ]
  }
  1 => Collection {#523 ▶}
  2 => Collection {#530 ▶}
  3 => Collection {#537 ▶}
  4 => Collection {#544 ▶}
  5 => Collection {#547 ▶}
]
```

Comment: Can you share the output before you do any modification?

Comment: You just need to define the relationships in the model. And you will be able to get the desired results. Please have a look at following [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships)

Comment: @ollieread edited the Q

Comment: @jsd Thank you. Check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, what you're looking for is something like the following;

```
$attributes = $productAttributes->pluck('attributesValue')
    ->flatten()
    ->unique()
    ->groupBy(function (AttributeValue $av) {
        return $av->attribute->name;
    })
    ->each(function (Collection $avs) {
        $avs->map(function (AttributeValue $av) {
            return $av->value;
        });
    });
```

Here's what the above code does;

- Pull the relationship `attributesValue` for all results.
- Flatten it out so we have one collection containing all `attributesValue`
- Make sure we don't have any duplicates
- We group everything so that we have something like `colour => (collection of colour attributesValue)`
- Now we cycle through our multi level collection, and map the instances of `AttributeValue` so that each is replaced with their value

I've not ran this code myself, but I *believe* this will work.

Comment: I think I know where you are going and will try it out! Thanks!

This is actually from the open source I am currently doing: 

ProductAttributeModel: https://github.com/jsdecena/laracom/tree/master/app/Shop/ProductAttributes

AttributeModel: https://github.com/jsdecena/laracom/tree/master/app/Shop/Attributes

AttributeValuesModel: https://github.com/jsdecena/laracom/tree/master/app/Shop/AttributeValues

Comment: Excellent!! You can add `strtolower($av->value)` the last mapping if you want it lower case.